# Cannot change screen resolution in MATE

Tags: resolution, mate

I just installed mate. It seems so windows98'ish and I cannot change the screen resolution. I change it to 1280x960 and it shows that it's changed but it doesn't change and resolution is still the same.

I have installed the proprietary ATI drivers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same experience myself, but resolved it with a [fix](http://forums.mate-desktop.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=175) to an ostensibly unrelated problem. From what I understand, this is an issue with `gnome-settings-daemon` and `mate-settings-daemon` conflicting.

Follow these steps:

```
cd /etc/xdg/autostart/
```

Always backup your files, just in case:

```
sudo cp gnome-settings-daemon.desktop gnome-settings-daemon.desktop.bak
sudo cp mate-settings-daemon.desktop mate-settings-daemon.desktop.bak
```

Now start the editing:

```
sudo nano gnome-settings-daemon.desktop
```

Then replace the text with the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=MATE Settings Daemon
Exec=/usr/bin/mate-settings-daemon
OnlyShowIn=MATE;
NoDisplay=true
X-GNOME-Autostart-Phase=Initialization
X-GNOME-Autostart-Notify=true
X-GNOME-AutoRestart=true
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-settings-daemon
```

Then edit the mate daemon

```
sudo nano mate-settings-daemon.desktop
```

Replace the line beginning with `Exec=` with this:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/mate-settings-daemon --no-daemon &
```

You should be set after a reboot.